# Issues dynamically updating records in SQL Server with MS Access front end

Tags: sql-server, database, vba, ms-access

I manage and develop a database that has a SQL Server 2014 back end with an Access 2010 front end. They are connected using an ODBC connection.

Over the last couple days there have been issues updating a particular set of tables that have a one to many relationship (let's say tables A and B where 1 A has many Bs). When inserting the data on the Access front end and focus moves away from table As fields onto table Bs, all fields related to table A are filled with #DELETE. Table B is the record source in a subform of table A's form.

[image: This is the result]

I tried editing the data in the tables directly. The first time I did so it failed, filling the fields with #DELETE and displaying the below message.  However, I can edit and append directly in the table sometimes. And sometimes when I go back to a record I just created and try to update it the fields will be populated with #DELETE. It seems to be very intermittent. And I know it says another user has edited the row, but this code produces the same error on our development database to which I only have access.

[image]

I did try adding data from SSMS through the "edit top 200" option. However, I got a similar result:

[image]

In all previous examples the data was added to the tables. However, Whatever UI that was being used needed to be closed and reopened in order to see the result. The tables can be appended and updated using SQL. However, I would like the flexibility that comes with connecting a form to a table in Access, instead of running SQL in VBA. No other tables in the database are acting like this and 
I can't seem to find anyone online with quite the same issue as me.

Does anyone know why this is happening or where I should start looking for an answer?

EDIT:

I should also specify that the two tables both have primary keys and all bit fields have a default value of 0, do not allow nulls, and do not have any rows in which they are null.

Comment: I had that issue in the past i have change all my table link to the DNS less table.please check this link http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this did not seem to fix my problem.

Comment: Do u have Pk on the table??

Answer (score 0):

Is there a key on all necessary tables, and do you have any bits that allow nulls? Access doesn't like the latter.

Comment: That was actually my first thought too. However, It did not make a difference.

Comment: usually this is the result of not having a PK or when you linked the table you did not have a PK. The other common issue is any bit (true/false) column needs a default set of 0 on the sql server side.

Comment: In addition to the PK, and correct defaults for any true/false columns, you also want to include a row version (timestamp) column in that table. Also, when you make these changes, you need to re-link the front end tables - if you don't do this, then your testing will not show or work when the table is fixed/changed. So in addition to PK, bits, and timestamp, you ALSO need to delete the table and re-link.

Comment: I do re-link the tables after I update them. I tried adding a timestamp field and it seemed like it might work for a minute. However, it fell back to its old routine after adding one or two entries. I did check older versions of the form and they actually seem to work. However, when I copy those versions to the current front end file they reproduce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The suggestion by Albert to add a timestamp field did improve the situation but did not resolve the overall issue in all cases. I did discover, however, that this issue happened when a new entry contained a null in any field regardless of data type or if it allows nulls or not. I set default values for all the fields and the issue when away.

I still don't feel like this is a perfect answer. I still don't know WHY it happened. If someone could explain why this would happen out of the blue, that would be great.

Here is a link to a description of the exact problem and some solutions that did not work for me. However, maybe it will help someone else:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/128809